# I need a tool which will create micro service in java (spring-boot)

Tags: java

Features provided by the tool will be

1) All DB it should support eg:- couch base and elastic search

2) Kafka

3) Iam integration eg:- keycloak , Okta , JwtToken

4) GraphQl

I have got a tool called jhispter but it doesn't supports graphql

Answer (score 1):

Use [Spring Intializer](https://start.spring.io/) to create the project and add the dependecies which you wants using gradle or maven. Then download project and extract it and edit in your own IDE( Intelij IDEA , Eclipse etc..)

Comment: i want a tool which will create dynamic micro service for me in spring-boot  like Jhispter creates but it does'nt supports graphql

Comment: Have you tried https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.graphql-java/graphql-spring-boot-starter maven dependency with Spring Boot

Comment: So the process is that i don't want another service which  i will make in graphql . I want a tool which supports all the mentioned features in it .